# node js set timeout in ssh in ssh2

Tags: node.js, ssh

How can I set a *timeout* for the connection to a ssh server?

Currently, I am connecting to the server with the following code:

```
var Client = require('ssh2');

var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function(){
    console.log("connected");
});
conn.on('error', function(){
    console.log("fails");
});
conn.connect({
    host: ip,
    port: 22,
    username: user,
    password: password
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `readyTimeout` in the `connect` options like this :

```
conn.connect({
    host: ip,
    port: 22,
    username: user,
    password: password,
    readyTimeout: 5000
});
```

This will cancel any connection that is not ready within 5 seconds.

You can read more about it in the [documentation of ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2#client-methods).

Comment: It does work (the default timeout is 20 seconds) however it is unclear how to handle the timeout error. It just crashes the Node app.